# Do you use 'a man of effort'?

Tags: word-usage

I'm a Korean. In a Korean textbook, there's 'He's a man of effort.'
Do you use this expression?
then

Comment: Hello Laman. No, it's not an expression I've seen or heard, and it doesn't appear in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+man+of+effort&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)

Comment: Yes, it is not a native North American English expression

Comment: I will understand it means a person who always gives an effort. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, @LAMON, that is how I would understand it; but you asked whether we use it, and we do not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a fair number of google book findings of the phrase **a man of great effort** and **a man of effort**, the former bieng more used. I cite but two and recognize it is not frequently used in AmE, but these 2 contemporary uses suggest it is not unknown in AmE.

*[How To Be A Loved And Respected Game Company President](https://www.nyfa.edu/student-resources/how-to-be-a-game-company-president-like-satoru-iwata/)* (Like Satoru Iwata) NY Film Academy 2015:

> “He was **a man of effort**.” “Even though he didn't start out in the
>   managing field, he read numerous management books, he would ask for
>   advice ...

and

*Ichiro keeps 'em Guessing about Future*  [Sandusky Register](http://www.sanduskyregister.com/story/201903180032) 2019, an article about the Mariners left fielder Ichiro Suzuki:

> "Yes, we are selling well because Ichiro is a **man of effort**," said
>   Yu Takamiya, a vendor answering questions through his translator app.

Comment: Both of those examples are translations from Japanese, not native English/American prose; I assume it's a fairly common Japanese expression but that doesn't mean it's a common English-language expression.